# How would I add text to this matplotlib graph?

Tags: python, text, graph, patch

I have the following code and graph and am wondering how I could add some text to it. On each bar I would like the min (where it begins) and the max (where it ends) displayed just inside the boxes and I would also like to place the average of each data set where it falls inside the box. The code is what I already have and the link goes to an example of what the final product should look similar too.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.patches as patches

    preRawData = [60,55,67,68,70,71]
    postRawData = [71,75,80,77,73,74]

    dataDict = {}
    delta = 0.4

    minPre = min(preRawData)
    minPost = min(postRawData)
    maxPre = max(preRawData)
    maxPost = max(postRawData)
    preAverage = sum(preRawData)/len(preRawData)
    postAverage = sum(postRawData)/len(postRawData)

    preRange = (minPre, maxPre)
    postRange = (minPost, maxPost)

    dataDict.update({'Pre' : preRange})
    dataDict.update({'Post' : postRange})

    yspan = len(dataDict)
    yplaces = [.5+i for i in range(yspan)]
    ylabels = sorted(dataDict.keys())

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_yticks(yplaces)
    ax.set_yticklabels(ylabels)
    ax.set_ylim((0,yspan))

    preStart, preEnd = dataDict['Pre']
    postStart, postEnd = dataDict['Post']

    low, hi = dataDict[ylabels[0]]

    ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((postStart,yplaces[0]- 
    delta/2.0),postEnd-postStart,delta, edgecolor='black', 
    facecolor='red'))
    if postStart<low : low=postStart
    if postEnd>hi : hi=postEnd

    ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((preStart,yplaces[1]- 
    delta/2.0),preEnd-preStart,delta, edgecolor='black', 
    facecolor='green'))
    if preStart<low : low=preStart
    if preEnd>hi : hi=preEnd

    ax.plot((low,hi),(0,0))

    xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
    ax.hlines(range(1, yspan),xmin,xmax)
    ax.grid(axis='x')

    plt.show()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FEWa.jpg

Comment: you need to look into plt.text() - you can set the x and y parameters to locate the text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bold annotated text in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36162414/bold-annotated-text-in-matplotlib)